# how to fill new column with ID for each dataframe in list of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported a list of files I want to work with, pretend:

```
dfnames = ['df1.tsv', 'df2.tsv', 'df3.tsv']
```

Then I opened each df and got my list of dfs:

```
df1 = {'0': ['stuff', 'stuff2', 'stuff3']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = {'0': ['more stuff', 'more stuff2', 'more stuff3']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df3 = {'0': ['even more stuff', 'even more stuff2', 'even more stuff3']}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)

dflist = [df1, df2, df3]
```

where dflist looks like:

```
[        0
 0   stuff
 1  stuff2
 2  stuff3,
              0
 0   more stuff
 1  more stuff2
 2  more stuff3,
                   0
 0   even more stuff
 1  even more stuff2
 2  even more stuff3]
```

I'm wondering how can i fill down a new column with the file name from which the dflist[i] came from? Ie. I want to get something like:

```
[        0  sample
 0   stuff  df1.tsv
 1  stuff2  df1.tsv
 2  stuff3, df1.tsv
              0   sample
 0   more stuff   df2.tsv
 1  more stuff2   df2.tsv
 2  more stuff3,  df2.tsv
                   0   sample
 0   even more stuff   df3.tsv
 1  even more stuff2   df3.tsv
 2  even more stuff3   df3.tsv   ]
```

I know how to do it for each df manually:

```
df1['sample'] = '1'
print(df1)
        0 sample
0   stuff      1
1  stuff2      1
2  stuff3      1
```

but i have a lot of files so wondering how to do it in a for loop. Thanks

Comment: How are you reading the .tsv to  DataFrame? Can you post that code?

Comment: In essence, i imported all the files from a folder ```path = 'path/folder'
files = [filename for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path)) if filename.startswith('barcodes-')]``` then i open each file and create a list with ```barcode_list = [pd.read_csv(path + f, sep='\t', header=None) for f in files]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
So starting from:

```
#retrieve files starting with 'barcodes-' from folder in specified path
path = 'path/folder/' 
files = [filename for filename in sorted(os.listdir(path)) if filename.startswith('barcodes-')]
#read all files and save in list
listdf = [pd.read_csv(path + f, sep='\t', header=None) for f in files]
```

and solving for what i wanted:

```
#add column with each file name of the df
for filename, filedf in zip(files, listdf):
    filedf['sample'] = filename
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want:

```
dflist = list()
for file in dfnames:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df["sample"] = file
    dflist.append(df)
```

Comment: how can i save for each df? it works, minus only returning the last df. So how can i save it at each iteration of the list (if that makes sense)?

Comment: @kas - See the edit!

Comment: okay, alternatively, i solved my own issue with the code above:) thank you though!